# How to implement Authentication using RestSharp for windows phone 7.5

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7.1, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I need to log in to the application using Google, Facebook accounts. I just saw about the RestSharp and i can't find how to implement it for WP7.5. I saw some samples available in the github and restsharp.org, but still i didn't get the exact usage of it. could please help me to understand about restsharp and how to implement it for windows phone 7.5... Since i'm new to this concept...

Thanks